# Insert into postgres table with select and autoincrement

Tags: postgresql

I want to move data from a table T1 to another table T2. T1 has an autoincrement id, which is consequente of the JPA annotations @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) with Spring Data implementation.

```
insert into T1(id, dataColumn)
(select NULL, dataToCopy
from T2)
```

This doesn't work, as it reports an error on the violation of the non-null constraint on the id field. How can I insert my data in this case?

Comment: Describe  "doesn't work". Show the actual error message you are getting, values you are passing to insert etc if you want appropriate solution.

Comment: It violates the non-null constraint on the ID field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I cannot make the insert that way is that autoincrement is not set on the id column. The reason for not having autoincrement is that setting the a generator for the id leads to the need of making an additional select statements to get the next value from a database sequence.